# How do I get this to POST with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I cannot figure this out, I have asked a couple people and we're stumped. I don't usually use AJAX but I kinda feel like I have to in this instance.

Could someone else me out with this?

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <body>
  <center>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <form>
    Tell your device what to do!<br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="arg" value="on">Turn the LED on.</input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="arg" value="off">Turn the LED off.</input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="arg" value="blueSwap">Toggle Blue.</input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="arg" value="allSwap">Toggle All.</input>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Do it!"/>
  </form>
  <br>
  </center>

  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    let url = 'https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/2f0021000547353138383138/led?access_token=150a347fb4277975913f5dfe24e2fb739171b3c5'

    $('form').on('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      let data = $(this).serialize()
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data
      }).done(() => {
        console.log('sent')
      })
    })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a poorly formed question. For advice see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Whats the question? In all cases done() is called.

Answer (score 1):

Not all browser support [Arrow Function](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions). You can try with regular ECMAScript 5, and see it works.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rab5j0ua/

Please make sure input tag is `<input.../>` not `<input...>...</input>`

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
    <center>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <form>
            Tell your device what to do!<br>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="arg" value="on" />Turn the LED on.
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="arg" value="off" />Turn the LED off.
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="arg" value="blueSwap" />Toggle Blue.
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="arg" value="allSwap" />Toggle All.
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Do it!" />
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <br>
    </center>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        var url = 'https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/2f0021000547353138383138/led?access_token=150a347fb4277975913f5dfe24e2fb739171b3c5'

        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: data
            })
                .success(function (result) {
                    $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(result));
                    console.log(result);
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something so small, yet so devastating :p... Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me as is.

Perhaps wrap your script in this:

```
$(function(){

...

});
```

This will wait to run the code (thus binding the `submit` event) until the entire page is loaded. It may be that your `<form>` doesn't load before the event is binded. However, as I said, I can see in the network tab in developer tools that the `POST` is sent to the server.

Comment: It must be something with the API then - I can't figure it out